# PowerBI multiple values in same column displayed as table format with no data

Tags: sharepoint, powerbi, powerbi-datasource

I'm trying to create a PowerBi dashboard from SharePoint list. The problem is one of the column contains "People or Group" where it intakes multiple names. This column is read as a table in PowerBi and when expanded, returns empty though there is data. Similarly, I have another column with "People or Group" but it only takes one name which works fine when expanded returning values.

```
Sample Data
ColA   ColB         ColC
1      John Doe     John Doe, Tim Apple
2      Tim Apple    Tim Apple, Steve Cook
3      Steve Cook   Tim Apple
```

From above, `ColB` works fine for data extraction but ColC return empty without any data.
I've attached a PowerBI screenshot for reference [image: reference].

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this. I used the column FieldValuesAsText to convert all the lists and tables as regular text without any issues. This column converts multiple columns at the same time, thereby saving a lot of time too...